# jquery select value from checked radio button

Tags: jquery, node.js, coffeescript, pug

I have two radio buttons:

```
div.span3
input.action.input(type='radio', name='action', value='push')
&nbsp;&nbsp; Push
&nbsp;&nbsp;
input.action.input(type='radio', name='action', value='pull')
&nbsp;&nbsp; Pull
```

I need to find out the value of the radio button that got selected/checked. I tried different ways but none of them worked:

```
$(@el).find("input[name='action']:radio:checked").text()
$(@el).find("input:radio[name='action']:checked").val()
$(@el).find(".action :checked").val()
```

I use NodeJS+coffeescript+Jade+JQuery, and here is the HTML for radio buttons:

```
<div class="span3">
  <input type="radio" name="delivery-action" value="push" class="delivery-action input">&nbsp;&nbsp; Push &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="delivery-action" value="pull" class="delivery-action input">&nbsp;&nbsp; Pull
</div>
```

Comment: What framework is creating these? Can you post the generated HTML?

Comment: i use NodeJS+coffeescript+Jade+JQuery, and here is the HTML for radio buttons: <div class="span3"><input type="radio" name="delivery-action" value="push" class="delivery-action input">&nbsp;&nbsp; Push
&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="delivery-action" value="pull" class="delivery-action input">&nbsp;&nbsp; Pull</div>

Comment: So the name is NOT action but delivery-action

Comment: it's typo, in the code the name is 'action'

Answer (score 0):

```
var selectedVal = "";
var selected = $("#radioDiv input[type='radio']:checked");
if (selected.length > 0) {
selectedVal = selected.val();
}
```